# Appending JSON object to the end of URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have this bit of code:

```
       //execute post (the result will be something like {"result":1,"error":"","id":"4da77536a2338","lockcode":"4af15b3725eb5cf3641d96f6c7a3b71d"})
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       $response = json_decode($result);

       //close connection   
       curl_close($ch);

       $imageHref = 'http://my.site.com/render?id=' . $response['id'];
```

But I can't append the id to the end of the URL for some reason.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "but I can't [...] for some reason" what exactly do you mean? Does the index not exist? Is the string not concatenating? In any case, you'll probably find it helpful to `print_r($response)` and make sure that `$response` contains what you think it does.

Comment: It does.  It holds exactly what I stated in the comments.  I am trying to get the id and append it to the end of the url.

Comment: stringify the json and then URLencode it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's becase json decode does not give you back an array, but instead an object. Instead:

```
$imageHref = 'http://my.site.com/render?id=' . $response->id;
```

Comment: @Gary it's actually the other way around. By default it returns obj. Setting to true returns assoc. array.

Comment: @Gary I think you've got that backwards, [at least for current version of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @Gary Green: Take a look at the examples in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code is failing is because you're trying to use an object as though it were an array. Replace your last line with:

```
$imageHref = 'http://my.site.com/render?id=' . $response->id;
```

Comment: He ninja'ed my comment by 1 second!